# Correct Russian equivalent of 'grasshopper'

Tags: перевод

My Kenneth Katzner dictionary translates **grasshopper** only as "кузнечик". And if you look up in virtually any internet dictionary, it is still "кузнечик". No more, no less.

However, I recently found that there exists a bug called **katydid**. Katydids have a green body, very long antennae, and if I do not mistake, they make their sounds using their wings rather than their hind legs.

Thus I have been confused. Katydid = кузнечик? Then how do you translate "grasshopper"? I'd appreciate more information about this issue.

Comment: I'm sure that an average English speaker would not be able to distinguish a katydid from a grasshopper. As well as an average Russian speaker would not be able to distinguish a _кузнечик_ from whatever a katydid is. It's all grasshoppers and кузнечики.

Comment: according to [Multitran](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=katydids) katydid in Russian is ***зелёный кузнечик*** and a number of other more scientific names

Comment: both are translated as "кузнечик" - this happens, terms for species not necessarily have one-to-one correspondence in different languages.

Comment: by the way famous (at least in my time) Russian children's song ["В траве сидел кузнечик"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=un-ZNqJAP4g) must be about katydid since according to the narrative it was **зелёненький**

Comment: Names of animals, fruits, plants in different languages is always a difficult problem. Usually lay people add something to classifications, so it could be a problem to define in a dictionary something which may have folk names. For example, the extinct *sea cows* were actually not cows, but the word cow was used in some languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be honest, this is the first time I encounter the word **katydis.**

[image]

Wikipedia says they belong to the family *Tettigoniidae (Настоящие кузнечики)* which belongs to suborder *Ensifera*, order *Orthoptera*.

[image]

**Grasshoppers** is an **informal group** of insects of the suborder *Caelifera (Короткоусые прямокрылые)* in the same order *Orthoptera (Прямокрылые)*.

To a Russian person without zoological background all these insects would perfectly qualify as **кузнечики.**

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that most urban residents do not distinguish **кузнечика**, **сверчка** and **цикаду**. Except that **саранча** can be separately noted, because it is much larger. Therefore, I think that even if you make a mistake in the choice of a word, almost no one will notice.
As for me personally, on the territory of the exUSSR I most often meet **grasshoppers**.

Comment: Me, too. I live in Moldova and I have encountered grasshoppers only; they are plentiful. Katydids probably live in North America or so.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you mean **саранча**? The difference is somewhere in the field of biology. :)

Comment: and entomology..

Comment: Well, I thought "саранча" is translated as locust. My excuses if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Alexander, locust is саранча и цикада, саранча is locust and grasshopper. :)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I'd say most Russian speakers would call those "кузнечик", with some (being more familiar maybe with nature) - "сверчок".